# Links doesnt appear as a submenu on a mobile

Tags: sub-menu

Help needed.
I've puted some pages in the submenu. Works perfect on desktop
On mobile the pages doesnt appear as a submenu for some reason

[Link](https://sonartech.co.il)

[image: desktop]

[image: mobile]

Comment: What are you using to generate the menus, superfish? Does it support a mobile view with submenus? What would you want that to look like, anyway - where would the sub menu go, would it expand like an accordion or something else?

Comment: i am making the menu without plugins,just the old fashion way Appereance > Menus. Would like the submenu to pop on hover